# Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization: Bearer

Tags: java, spring, yandex-money

Я начал работать с API Яндекс денег.

Вот мой код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/successPayment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String   testMethod(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = true) String code


    ) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {



  //Ссылка для перенаправления на страницу авторизации

        //https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=id_application&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/successPayment&scope=payment-p2p



        //Get Token

       URL urlgetAccessToken = new URL(" https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/token");
        Map<String,Object> paramsForToken = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        paramsForToken.put("code",code);
        paramsForToken.put("client_id", "id_application");
        paramsForToken.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        paramsForToken.put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/successPayment");


        StringBuilder postDataForToken = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : paramsForToken.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataForToken.length() != 0) postDataForToken.append('&');
            postDataForToken.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postDataForToken.append('=');
            postDataForToken.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytesForToken = postDataForToken.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connForToken = (HttpURLConnection)urlgetAccessToken.openConnection();
        connForToken.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connForToken.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connForToken.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytesForToken.length));
        connForToken.setDoOutput(true);
        connForToken.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytesForToken);

        Reader inForToken = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connForToken.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sbForToken = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cForToken; (cForToken = inForToken.read()) >= 0;)
            sbForToken.append((char)cForToken);
        String responseForToken = sbForToken.toString();

        ObjectMapper mapperForToken = new ObjectMapper();
        AccessToken JAccessToken = mapperForToken.readValue(responseForToken.toString(), AccessToken.class);

        String token=JAccessToken.getAccess_token();

        //request-payment

       URL urlRequestPayment = new URL(" https://money.yandex.ru/api/request-payment");
        Map<String,Object> paramsForRequestPayment = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        paramsForToken.put("pattern_id","p2p");
        paramsForToken.put("to", "номер_кошелька");
        paramsForToken.put("amount", "1.00");
        paramsForToken.put("message", "perevod");
        paramsForToken.put("comment", "perevod");

        paramsForToken.put("test_payment", true);
        paramsForToken.put("test_result", "success");



        StringBuilder postDataRequestPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : paramsForRequestPayment.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataRequestPayment.length() != 0) postDataRequestPayment.append('&');
            postDataRequestPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postDataRequestPayment.append('=');
            postDataRequestPayment.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytesRequestPayment = postDataRequestPayment.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connForRequestPayment = (HttpURLConnection)urlRequestPayment.openConnection();
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Authorization: Bearer ", token);
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connForRequestPayment.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytesRequestPayment.length));
        connForRequestPayment.setDoOutput(true);
        connForRequestPayment.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytesRequestPayment);

        Reader inRequestPayment = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connForRequestPayment.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sbForRequestPayment = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cForRequestPayment; (cForRequestPayment = inRequestPayment.read()) >= 0;)
            sbForRequestPayment.append((char)cForRequestPayment);
        String responseForRequestPayment = sbForRequestPayment.toString();


        return responseForRequestPayment;


    }
```

Но при его выполнении я получаю такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример токена для авторизации, который мне возвращает Яндекс:

4100115171799989.F304D864532B10B1B1BCF72C0BB2D7C07E651B145B8797CFCB372948F3FCD3B1576EFCB77C031597CBD226DC1F2421E09B5B63720B094B66FB566E4082F31922284E2EEF01B7EDFC388FA805E4C7D8B21734068F4A74A42F274F67E34CA47A8378EB9C5525002845060181BAF12BE9AB7414C34D3E91B159EFE61EB7124B5DF8

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с решением проблемы

Comment: попробуйте так `.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " + token);`

Comment: Не работает :.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " + token), теперь выдаёт:Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization:

Comment: `.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " +  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170850/java-illegal-characters-in-message-header-value-basic

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так, но ошибка всё равно осталась

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в том, что `Authorization:`, а надо было `Authorization`.